# Превратить первую строку во вторую, заменяя одни буквы на другие

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Задание:
На вход подается 2 строки. Нужно определить, можно ли превратить первую строку во вторую, заменяя одни буквы на другие, с учетом следующих правил:

- участвуют только буквы русского алфавита а-я;
- все буквы в нижнем регистре;
- за один шаг можно преобразовать все вхождения одной буквы в другую.

**Пример 1**
Входные данные: привет прикол
Выходные данные: 1
Преобразования (выводить не нужно):
в ⇒ к (прикет)
е ⇒ о (прикот)
т ⇒ л (прикол)

**Пример 2**
Входные данные: ааббдд ддббаа
Выходные данные: 1
Преобразования (выводить не нужно):
д ⇒ я (ааббяя)
а ⇒ д (ддббяя)
я ⇒ а (ддббаа)

**Пример 3**
Входные данные: абаб ааах
Выходные данные: 0
Преобразовать нельзя, так как 'б' не сможет оказаться одновременно 'а' и 'х'.

Я только понял, что можно втупую пройти один раз по слову и поменять буквы. Но похожу нужна более сложная логика, мой код работает не так, как нужно, со вторым примером. Не приходит в голову, как написать ещё ограничение, что не нужно ничего менять, как с третьим примером

```js
function solve(line) {
  function changeLetterInWord(word, fromLetter, whichLetter) {
    word = word.split('');
    for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      if (word[i] === fromLetter) {
        word[i] = whichLetter;
      }
    }
    return word.join('');
  }
  line = String(line);
  const strArr = line.split(' ');
  const russianRegExp = /^[а-яё]+$/i;
  if (strArr.length !== 2 ||
    strArr[0].length !== strArr[1].length ||
    !russianRegExp.test(strArr[0]) ||
    !russianRegExp.test(strArr[1])
  ) {
    return false;
  }

  // const russianAlphabet = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя';
  for (let i = 0; i < strArr[0].length; i++) {
    const item = strArr[0][i];
    if (strArr[0][i] !== strArr[1][i]) {
      strArr[0] = changeLetterInWord(strArr[0], strArr[0][i], strArr[1][i]);
    }
  }
  return strArr.join(' ');
}

const str = 'привет прикол';
console.log(str);
console.log(solve(str));
```

Comment: То, что вы хотите, можно сделать только если одной букве первого слова соответствует одна и только одна буква во втором слове и наоборот. Советую сделать так: берем первую букву первого слова, например, а, сравниваем ее с первой буквой второго слова, например д. Получается, что а соответствует д. Если в первом слове на i-ом месте есть еще буква а, то во втором слове на i-ом месте должна быть только буква д. Затем берем вторую букву первого слова, например л. Находим соответствующую ей букву второго слова. Если в первом слове есть еще буквы л, расположенные на j-й позиции, то во втором слове...

Comment: @МаксимФисман там во втором примере ещё видно, что идёт замена на букву я, которой нету во втором слове. Замена для того, чтобы можно было изменить в итоге слово.

Comment: ... На j-й позиции должна быть буква соответствующая букве л. Так проходим по всему первому слову, после чего заново проходимся по второму слову (таким же образом). Если хоть в один момент возникла ошибка, то преобразование сразу невозможно - можно выходить из цикла и заканчивать проверку с результатом false. Если что-то непонятно, то я через некоторое время буду за компьютером, напишу научным языком и приложу код (правда, на javascript я плохо, могу на каком-то другом языке, чтобы вы поняли смысл). Если нужен код - скажите на каком языке. Главное - не сам код, а чтобы вы поняли, а потом...

Comment: Можно будет перевести на javascript. Но я думаю, что описание по "научному" будет достаточно. Хотя возможно вам будет достаточно и того, что я уже написал

Comment: Ох ты господи... А может лучше Java, C++, C#? Просто я не знаю ни php, ни javascrit. Python чуть-чуть. Могу еще на алгоритмическом языке написать

Comment: @МаксимФисман я знаю C++, в принципе

Comment: Вообще хотел отдохнуть, но то, что вы так быстро ответили, говорит о том, что ответ вам важен. Так что сейчас пишу ответ

Comment: Автор вопроса, скажите, пожалуйста, насчет вот таких вводных данных: "ASDFG", "HELLO". Что должно выводиться? Просто моя программа работает в обе стороны. И здесь выведется false, вместо true. Если вам нужно true? то в своем ответе я написал, как можно подредактировать мое решение, чтобы оно работало только в одну сторону. Я сделал в обе, так как это практичнее что ли. А если нужно в одну, то нужно убрать всего 1 строку в моем коде

Comment: @МаксимФисман пока не знаю, завтра скажу

Comment: Ай ай ай, как не стыдно. Вступительная задачка в школу программистов HH

Comment: @EugeneDenisov не переживай, я не решу эти задачки, конкурента для тебя не будет. Пойду дальше изучать Angular + Express + Mongo, мне не хочется сейчас изучать алгоритмы, чтобы воткнуть в эту задачку

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, посмотрите вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1164776/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2). Такой же вопрос как у вас, может там чего толкового напишут. Кстати, как вы сделали, что у вас код в вопросе можно сразу выполнить?

Comment: @МаксимФисман называется фрагмент кода в панели, там где пишется ответ

Answer (score 5):

Вам надо просто понять, есть ли такая трансформация из первой строки во вторую.

Эту трансформацию можно выразить как отношение символ-символ или простым словарем.

Мы просто пройдемся по слову и будем строить словарь пока он имеет смысл. Если найдем, что условие в словаре нарушено, то можно сразу вернть false.

Код на C#

```
public bool CanConvert(string str1, string str2)
{
    if(str1.Length != str2.Length) return false;
    Dictionary<char, char> map = new Dictionary<char, char>();
    
    for(int i=0; i<str1.Length; i++)
    {
        char c1 = str1[i];
        char c2 = str2[i];
        
        if (map.ContainsKey(c1) && map[c1]!=c2) return false;
        map[c1] = c2;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(CanConvert("привет","прикол"));
Console.WriteLine(CanConvert("ааббдд","ддббаа"));
Console.WriteLine(CanConvert("абаб","ааах"));
```

Вывод

```
True
True
False
```

Так как у вас ограниченный набор букв (только русские и только нижний регистр), то вы можете оптимизировать мое решение используя коды символов и тогда мой словать превратится просто в массив. Но скорость работы и потребляемая память будет все равно примерно такая же.

Comment: Dictionary в C# это как map в JavaScript, да?

Comment: Не силен в js, но это типичный словарь, как HashMap в java

Comment: Вот это вроде похоже что вам надо https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: есть, возможно, еще крайний случай, когда все буквы изначально заняты, и ни одну замену, не слив ключи не сделать

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov не очень понял, можно пример?

Comment: "аб вгд...я" -> "ба вгд...я". Вроде "а" и "б" нужно поменять местами, а никак, все буквы заняты. Поменяем "а" на "б" -- получим "бб", а из "бб" не получить "ба"

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov когда мы меняем а на б, нам также придется менять [б на а](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Pvt.png).

Comment: По условию, "за один шаг можно преобразовать все вхождения одной буквы в другую". Поменять одновременно (а на б) и (б на а) нельзя. Если на первом шаге "а" на что-то поменять, то таких букв станет две, т. к. все буквы в строке уже были. И из этой строки итоговую уже не получить.

Comment: Если бы в строке не было буквы "я", то можно:
(а на я), (б на а), (я на б)

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov хха, ваша правда. Я походу неверно понял само задание.

Comment: @tym32167 да, этот ответ не подходит, и я не знаю на каких вариантах не проходит

Answer (score 1):

**Описание решения.**

> Есть два слова: first и second. Задача собственно ясна. Создадим специальную функцию check, принимающую две строки и возвращающую true, если они соответствуют условиям задачи, иначе false.

Путь решения:

0. Если длины слов не равны, то возвращаем ноль
1. Цикл i от 0 до длины первого слова (можно и второго, т.к. они равны):
2. Записывам i-ю букву первого слова в переменную first_letter, а i-ю букву второго слова - в переменную second_letter.
3. Проверяем в цикле j от i до длины первого слова (ищем, есть ли еще first_letter в first ИЛИ second_letter в second
4. Если first_letter равно j-й букве слова first (то есть нашли повторяющуюся букву, теперь у нас буквы i и j в первом слове совпадают), НО second_letter НЕ равно j-й букве второго слова (то есть во втором слове буквы i и j не совпадают), то возвращаем false. То же самое, если second_letter равно j-й букву второго слова, НО first_letter НЕ равно j-й букве первого слова (наоборот).
5. Циклы проходят так по всем буквам обоих слов. Если никаких ошибок найдено не было, то по завершению обоих циклов возвращаем true.
6. Саму функцию check() вызываем откуда надо. Я вызвал из main().

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool check(string first, string second) {
    if (first.length() != second.length()) return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i++) {
        char first_letter = first[i];
        char second_letter = second[i];
        for (int j = i; j < first.length(); j++) {
            if ((first_letter == first[j] && second_letter != second[j]) || 
                (first_letter != first[j] && second_letter == second[j])) 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    string first, second;
    cin >> first >> second;

    check(first, second);
}
```

> Помучился я с вашим вопросом, потому что затупил, как правильнее реализовать. Но вроде все работает хорошо: я проверил, - так что будет для вас ответ, а для меня опыт:)
>
> > Если мой ответ был вам полезен, пожалуйста, поставьте галочку, приняв ответ. Если остались вопросы - не стесняйтесь задавать.

ВАЖНО! МОЙ КОД ПРОВЕРЯЕТ СТРОКИ В ОБЕ СТРОКИ, Т.Е. НАПРИМЕР ИЗ HELLO НЕЛЬЗЯ ПОЛУЧИТЬ ASDFG, Т.К. L НЕ МОЖЕТ ОДНОВЕМЕННО БЫТЬ И D, И F - МОЙ КОД ВЫДАСТ FALSE (КАК И НАДО), ОДНАКО ОН ВЫДАСТ ТОЖЕ САМОЕ И В ОБРАТНУЮ СТОРОНУ. ЧТОБЫ ЭТО УБРАТЬВОТ ЗДЕСЬ:

```
            if ((first_letter == first[j] && second_letter != second[j]) || 
                (first_letter != first[j] && second_letter == second[j]))
```

УБЕРИТЕ ВТОРУЮ СТРОКУ И УБЕРИТЕ || НА КОНЦЕ ПЕРВОЙ СТРОКИ. Я ПРОСТО РЕШИЛ СДЕЛАТЬ ПРОВЕРКУ В ОБЕ СТОРОНУ, НО ЕСЛИ НУЖНА В ОДНУ - ТО СДЕЛАЙТЕ ТАК, НЕ НУЖНА - ОСТАВЬТЕ КАК ЕСТЬ

Comment: Плюс вашего подхода - требоует мало памяти. Минус - работает за N^2, на больших текстах будет долго. Я бы также убрал проверку в обратную сторону, если автору она нужна, то проще будет вызвать `check(first, second) && check(second, first);`

Comment: Да, я уже написал про это, что можно убрать вторую проверку. У меня тоже была идея использовать словарь, как в ответе выше, но я посчитал, что это будет занимать много памяти лишней: у меня всего 2 переменных вместо длинного словаря. Но с другой стороны пришлось делать вложенный цикл. Ну тут уже нужно выбирать: память или скорость. Хотя это похоже за задачку по программированию. Обычную задачку, а не какой-то проект. Так что здесь не особо важно, скорость или память. Я не выбрал словарь, просто потому что решение с циклами легче, чем со словарями: просто проходимся по всем буквам.

Comment: А вообще и мое и ваше решение похоже не работают на текстах "абвгд... юя" и "бавгд... юя"

Comment: @МаксимФисман да, на этих трёх примерах работает, но сервис не принимает этот код, говорит, что не подходит.

Comment: Попробуйтес двумя строками в if и с одной

Comment: @МаксимФисман пробовал