# Задача. Преобразования слов

Tags: java

**Условие задачи**

На вход подается 2 строки. Нужно определить, можно ли превратить первую строку во вторую, заменяя одни буквы на другие, с учетом следующих правил:

- участвуют только буквы русского алфавита а-я;
- все буквы в нижнем регистре;
- за один шаг можно преобразовать все вхождения одной буквы в другую.

**Входные данные:**

Входная информация поступает из стандартного ввода в виде одной строки. В этой строке содержатся две подстроки, разделенные пробелом. Ваше решение должно учитывать вариант, когда на вход поданы строки разной длины. Некорректные данные на вход не поступают, дополнительные проверки не требуются.

**Выходные данные:**

В качестве ответа в стандартный вывод программа должна выводить **1** (если превратить можно) или **0** (если превратить нельзя).

*Пример 1*

**Входные данные:** привет прикол

**Выходные данные:** 1

Преобразования (выводить не нужно):
в ⇒ к (прикет)
е ⇒ о (прикот)
т ⇒ л (прикол)

*Пример 2*

**Входные данные:** ааббдд ддббаа

**Выходные данные:** 1

Преобразования (выводить не нужно):
д ⇒ я (ааббяя)
а ⇒ д (ддббяя)
я ⇒ а (ддббаа)

*Пример 3*

**Входные данные:** абаб ааах

**Выходные данные:** 0

Преобразовать нельзя, так как 'б' не сможет оказаться одновременно 'а' и 'х'.

Делал тесты на подачу следующих строк:

`абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя яюэьыъщшчцхфутсрпонмлкйизжедгвба`,`абаб ааах`,`ааббдд ддббаа`,`привет прикол`, `abcd pppp`, `палец пипец` - везде результат равен ожидаемому.

Ниже код на java, но программа всё равно говорит, что задача решена неправильно. Что я делаю не так?:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str = reader.readLine();

        int result = wordTransformCheck(str);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int wordTransformCheck(String str) {

        String[] words = str.split(" ");

        char[] word1 = words[0].toCharArray();
        char[] word2 = words[1].toCharArray();
        List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Character> letterList = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<Character> letterSet = new HashSet<>();
        Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();

        if (word1.length != word2.length) {
            return 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < word1.length; i++) {
            letterSet.add(word1[i]);
        }

        if (letterSet.size() >= 33) return 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < word1.length; i++) {
            map.put(word1[i], word2[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < word2.length; i++) {
            if (word2[i] != map.get(word1[i])) return 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < word1.length; i++) {

            if (word1[i] != word2[i]) {

                for (int j = 0; j < indexList.size(); j++) {
                    if (i == indexList.get(j)) return 0;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < letterList.size(); j++) {
                    if (word2[i] == letterList.get(j)) return 0;
                }

                char c = word1[i];

                for (int j = i; j < word1.length; j++) {
                    if (word1[j] == c) {
                        word1[j] = word2[i];
                        indexList.add(j);
                        letterList.add(word2[i]);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                letterList.add(word1[i]);
            }
        }

        return Arrays.equals(word1, word2) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: А какой результат у вас считается ожидаемым в абвгд... и яюэ...

Comment: [А вот это вот что](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1163395/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: У Вас там JS, а тут Java ))

Comment: А откуда эта задача?

Comment: Оттуда же откуда и у вас ;)

Comment: Не понял. У меня ниоткуда. Ссылка - это вообще не мой вопрос

Comment: я столкнулся с новой проблемой - буква "ё". Если отправлять строку "фывё ёвыф" результат 0, а если отправляю "фыё ёыф" - рузультат 1. Вот как так?

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что адресовать его следует автору проверяющей системы